# How can I use AccessibilityService.getWindows() to obtain a traversable AccessibilityNodeInfo?

Tags: java, android, accessibility, android-5.0-lollipop, accessibilityservice

I am writing an `AccessibilityService` for Android and, up to API level 20, I have been using the `AccessibilityEvent.getSource()` method to obtain a traversable `AccessibilityNodeInfo` when `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)` is triggered. Although the resulting `AccessibilityNodeInfo` does not always reflect the content of the screen, it is still possible to work with it.

Starting on API level 21, the new `AccessibilityService.getWindows()` is supposed to be not only able to better represent the view hierarchy (i.e., Z-ordering is respected), but it is also supposed to be able to expose a node that includes all views in the current input method (IME). I would like to take advantage of this but I have not been able to do so and I do not know what exactly I am doing wrong. Incidentally, I have been unable to find any more detailed information on how to do this, other than the very minimal java docs.

I have already done the following:

- Configured service to retrieve window content (`android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"`)
- Added `flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows` to service flags

My code is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
            ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodes = getNodesFromWindows();
                switch (event_type) {
                case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED:
                case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED:
                case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED:
                //case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
                case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
                case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED:
                case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED:
                //case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
                    updateTargetLeafs(nodes);
                }
}
```

where getNodesFromWindows() does the following:

```
private ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> getNodesFromWindows() {
    List<AccessibilityWindowInfo> windows = getWindows();
    ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> nodes =
            new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();
    if (windows.size() > 0) {
        for (AccessibilityWindowInfo window : windows) {
            nodes.add(window.getRoot());
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

after this, `updateTargetLeafs()` collects all clickable, enabled and visible nodes into a separate `AccessibilityNodeInfo` `ArrayList` so I can index and access them at will (see below). When using `AccessibilityEvent.getSource()` on API Level 20 and below, the size of this array is always close to the number of views on the screen, but when I use `AccessibilityService.getWindows()` the size is almost always 1 (sometimes 0), and the bounds of the only `AccessibilityNodeInfo` in the list are always outside of the screen.

EDIT: Add the code for iterating through all nodes children (where `mNodes` is the output of `getNodesFromWindows()`):

```
        ...
        ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> theseleafs =
                    new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();
        AccessibilityNodeInfo thisnode;
        Queue<AccessibilityNodeInfo> q =
                new LinkedList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();
        for (AccessibilityNodeInfo n : mNodes) {
            q.add(n);
        }
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            thisnode = q.poll();
            if (shouldIncludeNode(thisnode)) {
                //Add only if it fulfills all requirements!
                theseleafs.add(thisnode);
            }
            for (i=0; i<thisnode.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo n = thisnode.getChild(i);
                if (n != null) q.add(n); // Add only if not null!
            }
        };
        LogD("MyTag", theseleafs.size() + " leafs in this node!");
        ...
```

Odd, I know, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can get access of windows content using `getChild()` method.
In your `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)` you can do like below.

```
@Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
          AccessibilityNodeInfo mSource = event.getSource();
          int child = mSource.getChildCount();
          // iterate through all child of parent view
          for (int i=0; i<child; i++){
            AccessibilityNodeInfo childNodeView = mParent.getChild(i);
            // Do something with this window content
          }
}
```

Comment: i have one doubt. we are getting all child node thats ok but how to get the source of all child nodes? Is this Possible? through the event we can get source of node which is triggered by some event. for child nodes how we can get source? @vsvankahede

Comment: First get parent of source node by getParent(). Then find number of  the child of parent by getChildCount(). Use for loop and iterate through all child and store there reference to ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>. Now you can do what ever you want with this accessibility node

Comment: yeah but how to get the source of child nodes?

Comment: Please read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord.html#getSource()

Comment: what do you mean by 'source' of child nodes? In `AccessibilityService` you receive `AccessibilityEvent`s and when you call `getSource()` on one event, you get an `AccessibilityNodeInfo` object. So, the node is the source, means the source of the event.

Comment: @vsvankhede I specifically mentioned that I am currently using event.getSource() and that it is working. This does not answer the question at all, which is... how to obtain the accessibility information using the new getWindows() method available in API Level 21 and above.

Answer (score 0):

getNodesFromWindows() is only returning a List of root nodes. You need to iterate through its children to collect all nodes in the window.

Comment: yup, that is exactly what updateTargetLeafs() does. I have updated the question to show this.